# Computing the $p_{T}$ spectrum of hadrons in pp collisions by knowing the $p_{T}$ spectrum of quarks

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, partons

Consider the differential quark production cross-section $d\sigma_{pp \to q\bar{q}}/d|\mathbf{p}_{T}|$, where $|\mathbf p_{T}|$ is the momentum transverse to the $pp$ beam line. Next, assume that the quark $q$ is fragmented into a hadron $h$. I'm interested in the question of existence of some analytical way allowing to compute $d\sigma_{pp\to h+X}/d|\mathbf p_{T}|$ by using $d\sigma_{pp \to q\bar{q}}/d|\mathbf{p}_{T}|$. If there is no such way, I would like to know how to compute $d\sigma_{pp\to h+X}/d|\mathbf p_{T}|$ by using all the possible data about the process $pp\to q\bar{q}$.

Could you please help me?

Comment: This is, of course, the job of a particle physics simulation. Most (nearly all?) experiments use Geant4 as the main engine, though that leave room for selecting different input (structure functions, for instance) and hadronization schemes.

Comment: @dmckee : thank you. But do these simulations use some analytical rule (which is independent on precise choice of hadronization rules) allowing them to get the desired $|\mathbf{p}_{T}|$ distribution for hadrons from the simulated $|\mathbf{p}_{T}|$ distribution for quarks?

Answer (score 1):

At high $p_T$ there is a factorization theorem (described in standard text books on QCD and collider physics) that determines the distribution of hadrons in terms of parton distribution functions, calculable hard cross sections, and fragmentation functions. The fragmentation functions are non-perturbative, but process independent (universal). At low $p_T$ the whole process is intrinsically non-perturbative, and all you have is models (string fragmentation etc).